# Deploying django project with apache 2.4 doesn't work publicly

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi

I am deploying a django project and I have configured the apache server with mod_wsgi as in many tutorials on the internet and the website was served successfully within the internal network using the server's IP and Port (80).

After setting the ServerName, I still can access the website within the internal network using the IP but I can neither use the domain name I want internally nor publicly.

I have made a special inbound rule in the firewall for my Port (80) to allow  accessing the server.

```
WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
ServerName my.website.com:80
#ServerName localhost:80

<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

What else can I do to make my server publicly available using the domain?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you modified the `/etc/hosts` to redirect to the IP address?

Comment: The point is that you have made your server acessible through the network. But you need some sort of mapping from `my.website.com` to that IP adress, you can not handle that at your machine locally. You need some sort of DNS that tells the machines in the intranet that it should look at your machine.

Comment: See for example here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/421491/what-is-the-purpose-of-etc-hosts

Comment: Aha! I think this is what I miss!
I have to ask the network admin to map the my.domain.com to the server IP.

Thank you very much